# How do I insert content of various MySQL fields in post?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to do the equivalent of a MSWORD mail merge in a post to insert variables from one of my databases.

I have a database with fields, such as name, street_address, city, state, and zip, plus photo_1.jpg

So the post might read:
"*name* lives on *street_address* in *city* and took this picture: *photo_1.jpg*.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I tried doing a search, but I could only find info on inserting INTO an MySQL database, rather than the reverse.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into shortcodes? Fetching the data from a mysql database isn't WP specific, but the inserting of arbitrary stuff from code into a post is, you'll just need to piece those two pieces of the puzzle together

Comment: I typically use the $wpdb class to query tables that are not part of the wp core. You can set it up so wpdb returns an array you can easily loop through and print the results as you wish. You can read about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

I also would vote for creating a short code. The shortcode code could pull data from a database/table, and 'build' the text you want with values from the table.

Lots of googles on how to build shortcodes - check those out, vs me putting some sample code here.

You would put the shortcode function in your Child Theme's function.php file. (You don't want to put it in your main theme, as any changes to the main theme's function.php would get overwritten during a theme update.)

Comment: Glad to help. (If you think others with a similar question might think any answer is helpful, a 'checkmark' is used to indicate that.)